# ChangeSet Issue : Cant we deploy picklist in changeset?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I was trying deploying some items in changeset and it was failing. After few changes I noticed that I cannot deploy `Picklist Fields` in `Change Set`.

Can we not  we use `Change Sets` to deploy `Picklist Fields`?

Comment: I have deployed picklist in change set. Are you sure they are causing the issue.?We have global picklist available in change set as well.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is this standard picklists?

Comment: It is not an error, but the picklist values are not being deployed via changeset. It is successful but when I checked those picklist values I deployed, that doesn't exists in the relevant picklist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Change Set to deploy Custom Picklists however it will not pickup custom values in the standard picklists such as Account.Industry, Case.Reason, etc.

To deploy the custom values in standard picklists you have to use a method of deployment that uses the Metadata API directly, e.g. Salesforce IDE, Salesforce Deployment tool or [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php). These will need to have the standard picklist field included in the 'custom fields' section of the package.xml and then it will deploy them.

This is a known issue and there is an [idea community topic](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG) for it.

Comment: also, if field is using Global Picklist; one needs to include the Global Picklist in the Changeset

Comment: raised a case, it seems we cannot move picklist values via changeset. Can be deployed using a Metadata API tool or has to be created/add manually in live organization.